# Чем отличается codePointCount от substring().length()?

Tags: java

Привет всем. В Java у строки есть метод `codePointCount`. Его можно записать так?

```
String s = "Hello, string!";
System.out.println(String.valueOf(s.codePointCount(0, 5));
System.out.println(String.valueOf(s.substring(0, 5).length());
```

Зачем вообще считать количество символов если можно просто отнять от второго аргумента первый

```
5 - 0 = 5
```

Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: http://javatutor.net/articles/how-long-is-your-string-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Разница проявится при появлении в строке символов, представимых более чем одним 16-битным блоком (code unit). Так как `length` возвращает количество 16-битных блоков, а `codePointCount` - именно символов.

Например, эмодзи состоят из пары 16-битных блоков, так как их код в таблице Unicode больше U+FFFF.

```
String s = "";
System.out.println(s.length() + " " + s.codePointCount(0, 2));  // 2 1
```

Соответственно, длина строки `s` будет 2, но символ в ней только один.

Comment: Можно пример, пожалуйста? Никак не пойму

Comment: @Flippy, https://ideone.com/pcF9kD

Comment: @КириллМалышев, переместите, пожалуйста, код из ссылки в ответ)

Comment: Вот теперь стало в сто раз понятнее, спасибо :)

Comment: @КириллМалышев, приведите, пожалуйста, пример случаев необходимости подсчета 16-битных блоков (code point).

Comment: @n199a, 16-битные блоки можно считать, чтобы узнать сколько байтов требует строка для хранения, а подсчёт code point показывает, сколько символов из таблицы Unicode было использовано.Я не могу привести какие-то более прикладные примеры, т.к. не работал с этим. Возможно, вам стоит задать отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Когда до людей дошло, что для кодирования всех мировых алфавитов одного байта не хватит, возникли многобайтовые кодировки и понятие code point.

Code point - это набор байт, описывающих ОДНУ графему(лигатуру) из одного из алфавитов(синтетические языки туда же), существующих на планете земля (смайлики, символы валют, математические символы и т.д. сюда же).

Диактрические знаки тоже являются code point кстати. (диактрический знак - это две точки над `е` в букве `ё`, например. Пример плохей - знаю, не докапывайтесь)

Собственно метод `codePointCount` возвращает колисество code point'ов, использованных в заданном куске тескта

Comment: У вас в ответе немножко не стыкуется терминология. Да, диакритический знак бывает отдельным code point'ом, но не любую графему можно описать одним code point'ом. Для этого в Unicode есть понятие grapheme cluster. https://ideone.com/4aMDdI -- вот пример составной буквы  ё (мы же обычно пользуемся цельной ё): два code unit'а, два code point'а, один grapheme cluster (да и символ, с виду, один).